# Python file is read only after unit test failure

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to create a unit test to test the following function:

```py
    def decrypt_keys(self, enc_password):
        with open ('id_rsa','r') as privkeyfile:
            pem_key = privkeyfile.read()
            print(pem_key)
            priv = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(pem_key)
        return rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(bytes(enc_password, 'utf-8')),priv).decode('utf-8')
```

However, the unit test fails with the following error:

```
ValueError: No PEM start marker "b'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'" found

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.012s

FAILED (errors=1)
b'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 ... rest of private key here ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

Immediately afterwards, as can be seen, the contents of the file are printed as is expected by the library. How can I ensure that the file is completely read before the function attempts to load it as an rsa key?

Comment: I'm confused. The error says that it's seeing a bad start marker for the keyfile, not anything about not reading the full file properly, which is what you seem to be asking about. Are you sure your file contains what you expect? The error message shows `b'` at the start of the line, so perhaps you've written the key file incorrectly from some other code?

Comment: @Blckknght I've updated the question to reflect that the file/what is read from the file is what is expected by the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your file contains Python binary string quotation marks in it, which is breaking the RSA reading code as it doesn't know how to interpret the `b'...'` around your private key.

I suggest opening the private key file in a text editor and removing those marks. You might also want to investigate where the file was written from, and fix it if it's some other part of your code. You're probably calling `str` on a `bytes` object, when you should be calling the `decode` method (e.g. `binary_key_text.decode()`). Or alternatively, you could open the file in binary mode (`'wb'`) when you're writing it, and then write the `bytes` object directly.

You could perhaps fix this issue in your reading Python code (with something like `pem_key = pem_key[2:-1]`, cutting off the first two characters and the last one). But if you add that to your code, then it will *only* work for mis-written files, not normal ones. That's how bugs get enshrined in software so that they can't be fixed in the future! (I suppose you *could* guard the slicing operation with `if pem_key.startswith("b'") and pem_key.endswith("'")`, but I'd only bother if the buggy file-writing code has been published widely and you really need to guarantee backwards compatibility.)

Comment: opening the file in binary mode when writing the bytes object solved the problem. Good catch!